# How to take data from mongodb atlas and add to table on website?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

the plan is to create a table on a website (link below) that users can add or remove data (a new row) to.

I have set up a form above the table (with POST) that takes data input into the form and then adds that data to a collection in my mongodDB atlas cloud.

This is fine so far, the problem is I dont know how to code to get that data to go from the db and append to the table (with GET)  adding a new row simultaneously.

eg. You add data to form and press submit.

1. The data you submitted goes to database (set this up)
2. At same time, data that was just submitted is taken from database and added to the table on the webpage (permanently until removed).

I can show you the page i created so you can see what Im trying to do.

https://epsl.herokuapp.com/transfer_list

I am using node, mongo, mongoose, express..to set  it up.

thanks.

Comment: When adding/updating a document in mongoDB, you could return the added/updated documents within the same request with mongoDB options {new: true}. Return that as response to the POST request, and update your table accordingly.

Comment: If you're using mongoose then just treat it like any mongo DB just change the url using `mongoose.connect(url)` to connect, `.find({})` to find, `.create({})` to create etc. if you want to get the document after creation try using something like `const newModel = await Mode.create(data)` in an `async` function

Comment: Ok thanks guys ill try this out